# Why do Rust's `Atomic*` types use non-mutable functions to mutate the value?

Tags: rust

I notice that Rust's `Atomic*` structs have functions which modify the value, such as [`fetch_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicUsize.html#method.fetch_add). For instance, I can write this program:

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};

struct Tester {
    counter: AtomicUsize
}

impl Tester {
    fn run(&self) {
        let counter = self.counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
        println!("Hi there, this has been run {} times", counter);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let t = Tester { counter: AtomicUsize::new(0) };
    t.run();
    t.run();
}
```

This compiles and runs fine, but if I change the `AtomicUsize` to a normal integer, it will (correctly) fail to compile due to mutability concerns:

```
struct Tester {
    counter: u64
}

impl Tester {
    fn run(&self) {
        self.counter = self.counter + 1;
        println!("Hi there, this has been run {} times", self.counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to Chris Morgans answer: you can read about the so called interior mutability [in the official `std` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html). `RefCell` is another example.

Answer (score 20):

It wouldn’t be very useful if it *didn’t* work this way. With `&mut` references, only one can exist at a time, and no `&` references at that time, so the whole question of atomicity of operation would be moot.

Another way of looking at it is `&mut` are *unique* references, and `&` *aliasable* references. For normal types, mutation can only safely occur if you have a unique reference, but atomic types are all about mutation (via replacement) without needing a unique reference.

The naming of `&` and `&mut` has been a fraught matter, with much fear, uncertainty and doubt in the community and documents like [Focusing on Ownership](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/05/13/focusing-on-ownership/) explaining how things actually are. The language has ended up staying with `&` and `&mut`, but `&mut` is actually about uniqueness rather than mutability (it’s just that most of the time the two are equivalent).

Comment: Rust's "internal mutability" is much more overwhelmingly common than `const_cast` is in C++. Perhaps it was a bad decision to name it with (im)mutability.

Comment: I use atomic for low-level lock-free operations. However, when I wrap the high-level structure with `Arc`, I cannot use its `&mut` methods. I end up with a solution to set all the first parameter of high-level APIs to `&self` (because `Arc` automatically `deref` to `&self`). It works, but it is not clear on mutability.